# Event listener for an equals button for calculator in Javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a calculator in Javascript and when you press the equals button, it outputs the result on the input box however it is working only for addition and not for other operations. Would be grateful for any help

***Code***

```js
let inputBox = document.querySelector('.input-number');
let numArea = document.querySelector('.nums');

let btn1 = document.querySelector('.btn1');
let btn2 = document.querySelector('.btn2');
let btn3 = document.querySelector('.btn3');
let btn4 = document.querySelector('.btn4');
let btn5 = document.querySelector('.btn5');
let btn6 = document.querySelector('.btn6');
let btn7 = document.querySelector('.btn7');
let btn8 = document.querySelector('.btn8');
let btn9 = document.querySelector('.btn9');
let btn0 = document.querySelector('.btn0');
let btnEqual = document.querySelector('.btn-equals');
let btnAdd = document.querySelector('.btn-add');
let btnSubtract = document.querySelector('.btn-subtract');
let btnMultiply = document.querySelector('.btn-multiply');
let btnDivide = document.querySelector('.btn-divide');
let btnClear = document.querySelector('.btn-clear');
let btnDelete = document.querySelector('.btn-delete');

let addition = false;
let subtraction = false;
let multiplication = false;
let division = false;
let previousValue;
let result;

btn1.addEventListener('click', button1);
btn2.addEventListener('click', button2);
btn3.addEventListener('click', button3);
btn4.addEventListener('click', button4);
btn5.addEventListener('click', button5);
btn6.addEventListener('click', button6);
btn7.addEventListener('click', button7);
btn8.addEventListener('click', button8);
btn9.addEventListener('click', button9);
btn0.addEventListener('click', button0);
btnEqual.addEventListener('click', Equals);
btnAdd.addEventListener('click', Addition);
btnSubtract.addEventListener('click', Subtraction);
btnMultiply.addEventListener('click', Multiplication);
btnDivide.addEventListener('click', Division);
// btnClear.addEventListener('click', Clear);
// btnDelete.addEventListener('click', Deletion);

function button1(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  inputBox.value += 1
}

function button2(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  inputBox.value += 2
}

function button3(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  inputBox.value += 3;
}

function button4(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  inputBox.value += 4;
}

function button5(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  inputBox.value += 5;
}

function button6(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  inputBox.value += 6;
}

function button7(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  inputBox.value += 7;
}

function button8(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  inputBox.value += 8;
}

function button9(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  inputBox.value += 9;
}

function button0(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  inputBox.value += 0;
}

// function Decimal(e) {
//  e.preventDefault();
//  inputBox.type = 'text';
//  inputBox.value+=".";
//  inputBox.type = 'text';
// }
function Addition(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  previousValue = inputBox.value;
  inputBox.value = '';
  addition = true;
}

function Subtraction(e) {
  previousValue = inputBox.value;
  inputBox.value = '';
  subtraction = true;
}

function Multiplication(e) {
  previousValue = inputBox.value;
  inputBox.value = '';
  multiplication = true;
}

function Division(e) {
  previousValue = inputBox.value;
  inputBox.value = '';
  division = true;
}

function Equals(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (addition == true) {
    result = parseInt(previousValue) + parseInt(inputBox.value);
    inputBox.value = result;
  }
  else if (subtraction == true) {
    console.log('success');
    result = parseInt(previousValue) - parseInt(inputBox.value);
    inputBox.value = result;
  } else if (multiplication == true) {
    console.log('success');
    result = parseInt(previousValue) * parseInt(inputBox.value);
    inputBox.value = result;
  } else if (division == true) {
    console.log('success');
    result = parseInt(previousValue) / parseInt(inputBox.value);
    inputBox.value = result;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form action="" class="my-form">
  <input type="number" class="input-number form-control">
  <button type="" class="btn btn-dark btn7">7</button>
  <button type="" class="btn btn-dark btn8">8</button>
  <button type="" class="btn btn-dark btn9">9</button>
  <button type="" class="btn btn-dark btn4">4</button>
  <button type="" class="btn btn-dark btn5">5</button>
  <button type="" class="btn btn-dark btn6">6</button>
  <button type="" class="btn btn-dark btn1">1</button>
  <button type="" class="btn btn-dark btn2">2</button>
  <button type="" class="btn btn-dark btn3">3</button>
  <button type="" class="btn btn-dark btn0">0</button>
  <button type="" class="btn btn-dark btn-equals">=</button>

  <button type="" class="btn btn-dark btn-add">+</button>
  <button type="" class="btn btn-dark btn-subtract">-</button>
  <button type="" class="btn btn-dark btn-multiply">X</button>
  <button type="" class="btn btn-dark btn-divide">/</button>
  <button type="" class="btn btn-dark btn-clear">CE</button>
  <button type="" class="btn btn-dark btn-delete">Delete</button>

</form>
```

Equals function does not work properly. It is at the end of the code.

There are no errors in the console and if there is an addition, it works but if there is any other operation, it simply doesn't do anything. Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Try setting the value of addition/subtraction ETC back to false in each IF statement after the line inputBox.value = result.  It shouldn't matter but there is no else before the subtraction statement.

Comment: No error in the console? I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: btn0 is not defined `. Your code doesn't even start running

Comment: @JeremyThille It actually is there in the code however it somehow didn't paste here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code made me laugh a lot, but don't get me wrong, I'm absolutely not making fun of you. I just thought, "Gosh, to think that I, too, used to write code this way like 12 years ago!" Today this looks to me like code from another age, but again, I'm not making fun, it's perfectly normal for a beginner to write this way, and what would *not* be normal is if I had the same level after 12 years.

Here's an improved version, logic-wise, of your little calculator, in 30 lines instead of 145, without manually selecting each button and attaching every listener one by one. I hope it will help you learn and improve.

Some other viewers will probably also laugh at my code, because I never code in pure JS (I use Angular and Typescript), and also because I use eval (and "eval is evil" etc.) but here goes :

```js
const numArea = document.querySelector('.nums'),
  buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-value]');

let stringToEval = "";

const clickHandler = event => {
  const value = event.target.attributes["data-value"].nodeValue;
  stringToEval += value;
  inputBox.value = stringToEval;
}

const execute = () => {
  inputBox.value = eval(stringToEval)
  stringToEval = "";
}

const clear = () => {
  inputBox.value = "";
  stringToEval = "";
}

const del = () => {
  stringToEval = stringToEval.slice(0, -1);
  inputBox.value = stringToEval;
}

buttons.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", clickHandler));
btnEquals.addEventListener("click", execute);
btnClear.addEventListener("click", clear);
btnDelete.addEventListener("click", del);
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="inputBox" class="form-control">
  <br>
  <button data-value="7" type="" class="btn btn-dark">7</button>
  <button data-value="8" type="" class="btn btn-dark">8</button>
  <button data-value="9" type="" class="btn btn-dark">9</button>
  <br>
  <button data-value="4" type="" class="btn btn-dark">4</button>
  <button data-value="5" type="" class="btn btn-dark">5</button>
  <button data-value="6" type="" class="btn btn-dark">6</button>
  <br>
  <button data-value="1" type="" class="btn btn-dark">1</button>
  <button data-value="2" type="" class="btn btn-dark">2</button>
  <button data-value="3" type="" class="btn btn-dark">3</button>
  <br>
  <button data-value="0" type="" class="btn btn-dark">0</button>
  <br>
  <button data-value="+" type="" class="btn btn-dark btn-add">+</button>
  <button data-value="-" type="" class="btn btn-dark btn-subtract">-</button>
  <button data-value="*" type="" class="btn btn-dark btn-multiply">X</button>
  <button data-value="/" type="" class="btn btn-dark btn-divide">/</button>
  <button type="" id="btnEquals" class="btn btn-dark">=</button>
  <br>
  <button type="" id="btnClear" class="btn btn-dark btn-clear">CE</button>
  <button type="" id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-dark">Delete</button>
</div>
```